# Get IP address of Nagios computer being monitored

Tags: nagios, nagiosxi

I'm trying to get the current IP address of each adapter on a monitored nagios computer.  I use the NRDP agent to push the status updates to the Nagios server.  I need to know what the current IP address is for each adpater on the computer.

I took a look at the Nagios Manual for CheckSystem Check_Network but didn't see any option for IP address.

http://docs.nsclient.org/reference/windows/CheckSystem.html#CheckSystem.check_network

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to say that you want the adapter MAC address?  That is available on the list:

```
MAC       The MAC address
```

If you're using NRDP passively posting the commands in your question would really help, thanks!